# How to Connect Power Bi to Visual Studio Team Service

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource, power-bi-report-server

Please, I'm trying to connect **Power BI** to **Visual Studio Team Services (VSTS)**. But, I get the message problem:

"The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish relationship of trust to secure channel for SSL / TLS."

Someone know how to properly connect avoid it?

Thanks in advance!
Helio Roots

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error when I entered the full account URL in the Account field while setting up the connection.  The fix was to use the account name only, not the entire URL.

So, instead of:
account-name.visualstudio.com

Only enter:
account-name